# Fazer DIV sumir com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Então gente estou com um problema, tenho dois input do tipo radio (sim e não) e preciso que quando o input "não seja selecionado a DIV suma e quando o input "sim" seja selecionado ele volte. Procurei em alguns lugares mas sempre dá algum erro tipo:

> ReferenceError: Mudarestado is not defined.

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if (document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.possuiCaderneta[0].checked)
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}

if (document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.possuiCaderneta[0].checked ||
  document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.possuiCaderneta[1].checked) {} else {
  alert('6 - A criança caderneta de saúde sem seleção');
  document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.possuiCaderneta.focus();
  return false;
}

if (document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.possuiCaderneta[0].checked) {
  function mostraDiv() {
   document.getElementById("visibilidade").style.display = "blockj"
  }


  if (document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.curvaPeso[0].checked ||
    document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.curvaPeso[1].checked) {} else {
    alert('7 - O peso da criança está com curva sem seleção');
    document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.curvaPeso.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.curvaAltura[0].checked ||
    document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.curvaAltura[1].checked) {} else {
    alert('8 - A altura da criança está com curva sem seleção');
    document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.curvaAltura.focus();
    return false;
  }
} else if (document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.curvaPeso[1].checked) {
  function someDiv() {
   document.getElementById("visibilidade").style.display = "none";
  }

} else {
  alert('6 - A criança caderneta de saúde sem seleção');
  document.cadastroDeAvaliacaoNew.possuiCaderneta.focus();
  return false;
}

function mostraDiv() {
  document.getElementById("visibilidade").style.display = "block";
}

function someDiv() {
  document.getElementById("visibilidade").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="rowCadastro">
  <span class="label">
 6 - A criança possui caderneta de saúde? <span class="campoObrigatorio"> *</span>
  </span>
  <span class="input">
 <input class="campoSelecao"
  type="radio" name="possuiCaderneta" value="1" onclick="mostraDiv()"
  title="Marque esta opção se a criança possuir caderneta de saúde" {selpossuiCaderneta1}=""/>Sim
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input class="campoSelecao"
  type="radio" name="possuiCaderneta" value="0" onclick="function (){someDiv()"
  title="Marque esta opção se a criança não possuir caderneta de saúde" {selpossuiCaderneta0}="" />Não
 </span>
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="rowCadastro">
  <span class="label" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">
Observe na caderneta da criança:
<div id="visibilidade">
 <div class="rowCadastro" id="visibilidade">
  <span class="label">
  7 - O peso da criança está com curva:
  </span>
  <span class="input">
  <input class="campoSelecao"
  type="radio" name="curvaPeso" value="1
  title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Ascendente" {selcurvaPeso1}=""/>Ascendente
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="campoSelecao"
   type="radio" name="curvaPeso" value="2"
   title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Descendente" {selcurvaPeso2}=""/>Descendente
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="campoSelecao"
   type="radio" name="curvaPeso" value="3"
   title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Horizontal" {selcurvaPeso3}=""/>Horizontal
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Peso: <input class="alinhamentoDireita" type="text" name="pesoAtual" id="pesoAtual" size="4" 
   maxLength="6" value="{pesoAtual}"  title="Peso da criança na realização da avaliação" /> Kg
  </span>
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="rowCadastro">
  <span class="label">
  8 - altura da criança está com curva:
  </span>
  <span class="input">
  <input class="campoSelecao"
   type="radio" name="curvaAltura" value="1"
   title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Ascendente" {selcurvaAltura2}=""/>Ascendente
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      
  <input class="campoSelecao"
   type="radio" name="curvaAltura" value="2"
   title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Horizontal" {selcurvaAltura2}=""/>Horizontal
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Altura: <input class="alinhamentoDireita" type="text" name="alturaAtual" id="alturaAtual" size="3" 
   maxLength="5" value="{alturaAtual}" title="Altura da criança na realização da avaliação"> m 
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem vários erros de sintaxe no seu código, nunca, jamais, em hipótese alguma, de o mesmo id para mais de um elemento (pelo menos de cabeça não me vem aonde isso pode ser útil) como você fez aqui: `<div id="visibilidade"><div class="rowCadastro" id="visibilidade">`

```js
function div(valor) {
  if (valor) {
    document.getElementById("visibilidade").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("visibilidade").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rowCadastro">
  <span class="label">
 6 - A criança possui caderneta de saúde? <span class="campoObrigatorio"> *</span>
  </span>
  <span>
 <input
  type="radio" name="possuiCaderneta" value="1" onclick="div(true)"
  title="Marque esta opção se a criança possuir caderneta de saúde"/>Sim
 <input class="campoSelecao"
  type="radio" name="possuiCaderneta" value="0" onclick="div(false)"
  title="Marque esta opção se a criança não possuir caderneta de saúde" />Não
 </span>
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="rowCadastro">
  <span class="label" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">
Observe na caderneta da criança:
<div id="visibilidade" style="display:none;">
 <div class="rowCadastro">
  <span class="label">
  7 - O peso da criança está com curva:
  </span>
  <span class="input">
  <input class="campoSelecao"
  type="radio" name="curvaPeso" value="1"
  title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Ascendente" {selcurvaPeso1}=""/>Ascendente
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="campoSelecao"
   type="radio" name="curvaPeso" value="2"
   title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Descendente" {selcurvaPeso2}=""/>Descendente
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="campoSelecao"
   type="radio" name="curvaPeso" value="3"
   title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Horizontal" {selcurvaPeso3}=""/>Horizontal
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Peso: <input class="alinhamentoDireita" type="text" name="pesoAtual" id="pesoAtual" size="4" 
   maxLength="6" value="{pesoAtual}"  title="Peso da criança na realização da avaliação" /> Kg
  </span>
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="rowCadastro">
  <span class="label">
  8 - altura da criança está com curva:
  </span>
  <span class="input">
  <input class="campoSelecao"
   type="radio" name="curvaAltura" value="1"
   title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Ascendente"/>Ascendente
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      
  <input class="campoSelecao"
   type="radio" name="curvaAltura" value="2"
   title="Marque esta opção se a curva de peso da criança está Horizontal" />Horizontal
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Altura: <input class="alinhamentoDireita" type="text" name="alturaAtual" id="alturaAtual" size="3" 
   maxLength="5" title="Altura da criança na realização da avaliação"> m 
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: na verdade eu tinha colocado o segundo id para um teste e esqueci de apagar depois. 

Mesmo resolvendo o problema aqui, lá continua dizendo que o valor fa função div é nulo ou não definido. Eu faço estágiario e faço manutenção nesse sistema, então estou tentando compreender certas partes dele ainda.

Comment: @DouglasNunes, tudo bem? Se possível, copia aqui todo html e js... fica melhor de nós entendermos e te ajudar da melhor forma, tranquilo?